# How can i change the default Auth Password field name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i want to change the default password field name of Laravel Auth, this because im using ORACLE, How can i change ? i tried this but i cant login

User.php

```
protected $table = 'SEG_USUARIOS1';

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->contrasenha;
}
```

RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [

        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:SEG_USUARIOS1',
        'contrasenha' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data)
{


    $user =  User::create([
        'nombre' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'contrasenha' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'verifytoken' => Str::random(40),
    ]);


    $thisUser = User::findOrFail($user->usuario_id); 
    $this->sendEmail($thisUser);
    return $user;
}
```

Im Using laravel 5.4

Comment: Don't change password input name, leave it password, make sure to also update the $fillable and $hidden arrays with the new field names and you should be good to go

Comment: it was ok the problem was im using another primary key name.. so i put this protected $primaryKey = 'your_id';

Answer (score 0):

My code was ok, the only problem was that I'am using another primary key,
so you have to use it in `User.php`

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your_id';
```